# learning mysql insert returns syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to make a simple insert statement of user... but it errors out... I tried with only values and it works, it must be something with the way I deal with arrays inside the insert statement?

ANy ideas?

```
                if ($new_user_data) {
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_year, user_sex, user_pic, user_level, user_password, user_email)
                                    VALUES ( ". $new_user_data['user_name'] .",". $new_user_data['user_year'] .",". $new_user_data['user_sex'] .",". $new_user_data['user_pic'] .",1,". $new_user_data['user_password'] .",". $new_user_data['user_email'] ." )");
                    print_r($mysqli->error);
                }
```

error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.coms )' at line 2
```

Comment: please echo to sql query. That would show a little more

Comment: @s.lenders what do you mean? I'm new to this please be specific :) You want me to echo mysqli->query? or $new_user_data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your strings in quotes:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_year, user_sex, user_pic, user_level, user_password, user_email)
                VALUES ( '". $new_user_data['user_name'] ."','". $new_user_data['user_year'] ."','". $new_user_data['user_sex'] ."','". $new_user_data['user_pic'] ."',1,'". $new_user_data['user_password'] ."','". $new_user_data['user_email'] ." )'");
```

I know i can't see all of your code, but it looks like you're wide open to SQL Injections.

Comment: Ty, that was it... I will sanitize everything before it reaches INSERT.

Comment: Yah and top of that,use a parameterised query, would not have got this problem either.

Comment: @salivan: Why sanitize?  Put on your Big Programmer pants and learn to use parametrized queries.  **Now is the time to learn the right way to do it.**

Comment: @AndyLester I already did. If you didn't notice you are commenting on 1 year old post.